# What is the number of all possible values of $[Z^{6}]$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Its given that $$[Z]=3$$
$$[Z^{2}]=11$$
$$[Z^{3}]=41$$

Then, what is the number of all possible values of $[Z^{6}]$ where $[\;\cdot\;]$ is floor function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$
[Z^k]=b\quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
b\leq Z^k<b+1 \quad\Longleftrightarrow\quad
b^{1/k}\leq Z<(b+1)^{1/k}
$$

Comment: Please elaborate a little more, what to do after getting the 3 inequalities?

Comment: You should intersect this three intervals, then you'll get a zet of all possible $Z$'s which satisfy your equlitites. Given this intersection you can find range of values of $Z^6$. I think the rest is clear

Comment: 19+27 = 46

Am I correct master?

Comment: possible values are 1681, 1682, ..., 1727(total 46)

Comment: hmm.. I got 47${}{}$

Comment: sorry, my bad :(